# How to validate with comparison against a blank value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails ActiveModel with two fields `date_from` and `date_to` and I want the model to be valid when (and only when)

- either of these fields or both are blank
- `date_from < date_to`

In other words, the model should be invalid only when both fields are set but they're in the wrong order. In that case I also want *both* fields to be marked as invalid.

I tried with

```
validates :date_from, comparison: { less_than_or_equal_to: :date_to }, allow_blank: true
validates :date_to, comparison: { greater_than_or_equal_to: :date_from }, allow_blank: true
```

But that fails when exactly one of the fields is set with

```
#<ActiveModel::Error attribute=date_to, type=comparison of Date with nil failed, options={}>
```

How can I make the comparison validation pass when the *referenced* field is blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with two separate `validates` calls by adding a conditional check with `if` option

```
validates :date_from, 
  comparison: { less_than_or_equal_to: :date_to },
  allow_blank: true,
  if: :date_to # make sure `date_to` is not `nil`

validates :date_to,
  comparison: { greater_than_or_equal_to: :date_from },
  allow_blank: true,
  if: :date_from
```

This will skip these validations if one of the dates is `nil`. When both dates are present it runs both validations and adds two separate errors, which may be not quite right, since it is essentially one error.

To make the intent of this validation more obvious, a `validate` method is a better fit

```
validate :date_from_is_less_than_date_to

def date_from_is_less_than_date_to
  return unless date_from && date_to # valid if date(s) are missing

  unless date_from < date_to
    errors.add(:base, 'Date range is invalid')

    # NOTE: to add errors to show on form fields
    # errors.add(:date_from, 'must come before Date to')
    # errors.add(:date_to, 'must come after Date from')

    # NOTE: to add errors only for date that changed
    #       requires ActiveModel::Dirty
    # errors.add(:date_from, 'must come before Date to') if date_from_changed?
    # errors.add(:date_to, 'must come after Date from')  if date_to_changed?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a lambda to `:if` which returns true only if both attributes, used for comparison, are present. So, basically, all you need for validations is this:

```
validates_comparison_of :date_to, greater_than: :date_from, if: ->(this) { this.date_from && this.date_to }
```